# How to retain last test case code coverage in sonar qube report if test is excluded

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

In Jenkins pipeline, 1st we are doing "gradle build" stage, where

```
       if(env.RUN_TEST_CASE.toBoolean()){
             bat "gradle clean build --no-daemon --no-build-cache"
       } else {
            bat "gradle clean build --no-daemon --no-build-cache -x test"
       }
```

Then, "Sonar Code Analysis", there

```
       if(env.RUN_TEST_CASE.toBoolean()){
            echo "sonrqube with test case"
            bat 'gradle --info sonarqube'
       }
       else {
            echo "sonrqube without test case"
            bat 'gradle --info sonarqube -x test'  
       }
```

Even after excluding the test case ([link1](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-do-i-prevent-the-gradle-sonarqube-task-from-running-tests/6674/7)) in sonar code analysis, it is overriding the previous coverage percentage to zero. It's not retaining previous value.

Is there any way to retain previous value if the test case is excluded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to retain previous value if the test case is excluded?

No